# how to give enable and disable for @html.textbox in controller in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How can I enable and disable a `@html.textbox` in controller in mvc3?

My textbox code:

```
@Html.TextBox("txtIden1")
```

After click button, how can I disable or enable the Textbox in controller.

I wrote button click event code in controller, like below

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.TextBox("txtCustomerFilter");
}

<button name="button" value="Submit">Save</button>&nbsp;
<button name="button" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
```

Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Customer(string button,
         customer customerInsert, FormCollection formvalues)
{
  if(button == "Submit")
  {
    //Code
  }
  else
  {
    //Code
  }

  return View();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you using a view model:

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public string Button { get; set; }
    public string Filter { get; set; }
    public bool Disabled { get; set; }

    ... some other properties that will represent the customer
        details
}
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Customer()
{
    var model = new CustomerViewModel();
    return View(model);
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Customer(CustomerViewModel model)
{
    if(model.Button == "Submit")
    {
        model.Disabled = true;
        //Code
    }
    else
    {
        //Code
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

and then have a strongly typed view:

```
@model CustomerViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(
        x => x.Filter, 
        Model.Disabled ? new { @readonly = readonly } : null
    )

    <button name="button" value="Submit">Save</button>
    <button name="button" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to have one attribute always and other optional? something like:

'@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AddFirstLine, Model.AutomaticAddress ? 
            new { '@class = "form-control", '@disabled = "disabled" } : new { @class = "form-control" })